# Разделение и объединение введенных чисел функции ` input()`

Tags: python, input, join, split

Программа принимает два вводимых значения, складывает их и выдает сумму пользователю.

Перед складывание с помощью функции `isdigit()` проводится проверка на то, что все введенные символы являются числами и проводится разделение чисел с помощью `.split()`, чтобы выполнить операцию увеличения значения `result`. Если обнаруживается наличие посторонних символов, то выводится сообщение об ошибке и функция запускается заново.

Если вводить числа, содержащие более одного знака, то числа не объединяются, вследствие чего происходит вывод ошибки ( в условии  `if-else` )

Не знаю как решить проблему. Желательно обойтись БЕЗ отдельного ввода каждого числа и проверки для него и БЕЗ использование `try-except`, если можно. Заранее спасибо.

Исходный код:

```
def sum():

   num=input('enter two numbers with space')
   '''ввод двух исел через пробел'''

   result=0
   '''присваивается результат суммы введенных чисел'''

   num = '0'.join(num)
   '''объединение введенных чисел через 0 ( ноль )'''

   if num.isdigit() == True:
       '''проверка на отсутствие символов кроме чисел'''

       '''разделение чисел по знаку 0'''
       num = num.split('0')
       '''увеличение result на значение введенных чисел'''
       for i in num:
           i=int(i)
           result+=i

   else:
       '''вывод сообщения об ошибке и запуск функции по новой'''
       print('you should enter only numbers')
       sum()
   '''вывод суммы'''
   print(result)

'''начальный вызов функции'''
sum()
```

Comment: 100+1 = ['1', '', '', '1'] при соединении и сплите по нулю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через try+except:

```
def summa():
    num = input('enter 2 nums: ')
    try:
        return sum([int(i) for i in num.split()])
    except TypeError:
        summa()
print(summa())
```

Без:

```
array = []

while len(array) < 2:
    a = input()
    if a.isdigit():
        array.append(int(a))

print(sum(array))
```

Comment: Забыл написать, нельзя использовать try-except

Comment: @VyQwe поставивший вам это условие плохо знает Python.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, скорее всего я просто неправильно понял задание и в нем не имелось в виду, что вводить числа нужно в одной функции `input`.

Comment: @VyQwe добавил вариант без try+except